# print_r blank space in output

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with arrays in PHP and I have noticed strange output with some of the values having an extra line of blank space as shown below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => data
            [tag] => data

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => data
            [tag] => data
        )
```

etc.

This alternates with every other element having the extra blank space until element 5. Then they all look like [1] until they reach element [9] which has the strange whitespace line again.

Some data is duplicate too yet this doesn't effect whether the two elements will have the same whitespace issue.

Can this cause me problems or does it show an issue within my code? Why do some elements have this additional whitespace?

EDIT:

I did a var dump, and I have identified that some of the tags have a newline after them.

e.g.

```
"tagexample
"
```

rather than

```
"tagexample"
```

This is confusing however because as I said, a lot of the tags are duplicates and used for multiple tokens and it seems random which is affected.

EDIT2:

I did var export and that shows the same result as above, i.e.

```
    'tag' => 'data
',
```

Comment: And what does `var_dump()` show? I'm going to take a stabbing guess at it including something like `\r\n` within the string/data.

Comment: I don't think that this will make you issues, but try this before print_r: `$arr = array_map("trim", $arr);` Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: Please, add `var_export` of your array.

Comment: are you... printing your array with `<pre>` first?  how is it being printed?  are the actual values correct?  or not?

Comment: @Rizier123 That wiped the array of data

Comment: @gloomy.penguin There is no <pre> being used, the data is never displayed to the user and is just used in internal processing. The values are all correct, just sometimes, a rogue newline will be added to the end of a tag.

Comment: ohhh but you're printing it, so you are using and displaying it somewhere.  if you're not displaying it, i'm not sure how you're getting the results of `print_r` exactly.  i'm gonna ask the important question again... is this an issue with actual whitespace in your data or is it just in the way `print_r` displays the data?  also, can you add a partial dump with `var_export`?  by using `var_export`, we can see your actual data with the quotes.

Comment: i'm still not sure if you want to trim the values or what.  [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) isn't a bad idea and shouldn't have wiped anything but whitespace by default.  trim takes a second parameter that tells it exactly what to trim, you can try using it with `\n` or `\r\n`  or something.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I'm using file_put_contents to send it to a file, which I'm using to work on a function that processes the tags. It was when using it like this that I noticed the extra space and asked the question. I assumed it was a quirk of print_r but have found out from var_dump and var_export that some of the tags have a newline in them. So yes, the issue is with the data.

Comment: k... so... try this: `foreach($arr as $index => $subarr) { $arr[$index] = array_map('trim','$subarr); } `

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I see we make progress with OP we are at the point where we were 20min ago! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894382/print-r-blank-space-in-output#comment44189922_27894382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$arr = array( 
               array( 'token' => 'stuff 1', 
                      'tag'   => 'data 1 
                                 ', ),
               array( 'token' => 'stuff 2', 
                      'tag'   => 'data 2 
                                 ', ),
               array( 'token' => 'stuff 3', 
                      'tag'   => 'data 3
                                 ', ), 

            );

print "<pre>";             
print_r($arr); 


foreach($arr as $index => $sub) {
   $arr[$index] = array_map('trim',$sub); 
}           

print "\n\n----------------------------------------------------\n\n";
print_r($arr); 



/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 1
            [tag] => data 1 

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 2
            [tag] => data 2 

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 3
            [tag] => data 3

        )

)


----------------------------------------------------

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 1
            [tag] => data 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 2
            [tag] => data 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [token] => stuff 3
            [tag] => data 3
        )

)

*/
```

could also be written as:

```
function trim_the_sub_array($sub) {
   return array_map('trim',$sub); 
}

$arr = array_map('trim_the_sub_array',$arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did what was written in your comment and that worked. I'll have a play around with the POS tagger I'm using and see if I can remove the problem at it's source but for now, this is a good fix and removes any blank spaces in the array.

Comment: @Kervate Do you even read the comments under your question?! almost 30min ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894382/print-r-blank-space-in-output#comment44189922_27894382

Comment: @Rizier123 - OP did read it and did reply.  OP did not realize it needed to be applied to the inner array and not the outer array.

Comment: @Rizier123 I replied to you and said that wiped the array. Without the subarray fix offered by gloomy.penguin, it just erased all of the data.

Answer (score 1):

print_r() is a debugging function (http://php.net/print_r) and you need not worry about the whitespaces if you are using it for debugging. If you use it for output (say for a log), var_export() (http://php.net/var_export) would be a better choice since it prints actual PHP code for defining the array in question.

As you have mentioned, if some data is duplicated and if it's not the intended behavior then probably there is an issue in your code. You will be able figure that out by focusing on where the array is populated.

Comment: Print_r is being used for debugging, I need to process the tags but don't need to log any of it. The code that populates the array is from an external POS library I am using, hence didn't write it myself. Looking through the code however, it doesn't seem to have any issues with it's tag assignment.

Comment: After answering, I saw you have used var_dump(). Can you use var_export() and see so that it would show exact array definition? You can also echo() individual elements to see whether they actually contain newlines or is simply a problem with debugging functions.

Comment: I have used var_dump and var_export and both show that the problem is with some of the tags having a newline appended.